# How to get current auto generated document ID during posting with cloud firestore in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm posting a post of location with firestore and save their data to the database on button click.
Every button click it's generating auto DocumnetID and want to save this ID to the database in same time.

Code:

```
await firestore.collection("Table_Name").document().setData({
        "SpotLatLong":new GeoPoint(spotlat, spotlong) ,
        "spotName": placeNameController.text,
        "SpotImage":spotImage,
        "UserID":uid,
        "SpotActivity":spotActivity,
        "SpotDocumentID": firestore.collection("Table_Name").document().documentID.toString()//this line generates Different documentID, which is wrong
      }).then((onValue){
        StyleWidget.showToast(msg: "Created spot to the table");
        Navigator.pop(context);
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String id= await firestore.collection("Table_Name").document().documentID().toString;

await firestore.collection("Table_Name").document(id).setData({
        "SpotLatLong":new GeoPoint(spotlat, spotlong) ,
        "spotName": placeNameController.text,
        "SpotImage":spotImage,
        "UserID":uid,
        "SpotActivity":spotActivity,
        "SpotDocumentID":id //this line generates Different documentID, which is wrong
      }).then((onValue){
        StyleWidget.showToast(msg: "Created spot to the table");
        Navigator.pop(context);
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Hope help this

Answer (score 1):

To have to programatically add the new Document to document id as followind,

```
// Your Firestore Database Reference
var tableReference = Firestore.instance.collection("Tables");

// Push a new ID every time like this
var ID = groupReference.document().documentID;

// Set Data to the new Document ID
await firestore.collection("Table_Name").**document(ID)**.setData({
        "SpotLatLong":new GeoPoint(spotlat, spotlong) ,
        "spotName": placeNameController.text,
        "SpotImage":spotImage,
        "UserID":uid,
        "SpotActivity":spotActivity,
        "SpotDocumentID": firestore.collection("AddSpot").document().documentID.toString()//this line generates Different documentID, which is wrong
      }).then((onValue){
        StyleWidget.showToast(msg: "Created spot to the table");
        Navigator.pop(context);
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var docRef = await firestore.collection("Table_Name").document().setData({
        "SpotLatLong":new GeoPoint(spotlat, spotlong) ,
        "spotName": placeNameController.text,
        "SpotImage":spotImage,
        "UserID":uid,
        "SpotActivity":spotActivity,
        "SpotDocumentID": firestore.collection("AddSpot").document().documentID.toString()//this line generates Different documentID, which is wrong
      }).then((onValue){
        StyleWidget.showToast(msg: "Created spot to the table");
        Navigator.pop(context);
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Get document reference by this way

```
docRef.documentID
```

Comment: Looks like setData() returns void not document reference